# How to set default value for SwitchPreference in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

Does anyone used `SwitchPreference` class from Android and knows how to set the default value?  I have implemented it programmatically:

```
SwitchPreference switch = new SwitchPreference(this);
switch.setKey("preference_my_key");
switch.setTitle(R.string.preference_title_my_title);
switch.setSummary(R.string.preference_summary_my_summary);
Boolean isChecked = Manager.myMethodIsChecked(MyActivity.this);
switch.setChecked( isChecked ); 

switch.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener()  {                
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
    try {
            boolean selected =   Boolean.parseBoolean(newValue.toString());      
        if ( !selected ) {
            //do something
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }               
   return true;
   }
});         
category.addPreference(switch);
```

Preferences saves all values into its XML file: `app_package_name_preferences.xml`. First time when app is loaded, switch has default "**false** " values. But I need sometimes to make default value "**true**". I tried few methods,but nothing works.

```
switch.setChecked( true );  
switch.setDefaultValue(true);
```

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific as to what you want to achieve. And "switch" in the code above is not a boolean, and can therefore not be set to true or false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I told, I write preferences programmatically:

```
PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
PreferenceCategory catView = new PreferenceCategory(this);
catView.setTitle(R.string.preference_category_view);
root.addPreference(catView);

final SwitchPreference switchSplash= new SwitchPreference(this);
switchSplash.setKey(PreferenceKeys.SPLASH); 

//-----the above code----
switchSplash.setChecked(false);       // LINE 1
catView.addPreference(switchSplash);  // LINE 2
```

While debugging I found that `true` value is set in *LINE 1*, but when I add `switchSplash` into `catView`, the values of `switchSplash` is reset to `false`, because `catView` sets values from preferences.xml.
That's why I changed all needed values into the XML

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = root.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().edit();
editor.putBoolean(PreferenceKeys.SPLASH, true);  
editor.commit();
```

Comment: I think im having the same problem as you, but your solution is not very clear. What did you do then? I think my switchPreference is not reading my shared preferences, if i use CheckBoxpreference everything works well, but with SwitchPreference, everytime i open my settings activity it is set to false, which is not even the default value!

Comment: What if I have multi SwitchPreference ? I think it will set all the values to true.

Comment: @Lidia Following your explanation I think you mean `switchSplash.setChecked(true); `  and not `switchSplash.setChecked(false); ` right?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the XML attribute `android:defaultValue="true"` on your `<SwitchPreference />` to set the default to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to get the boolean out of newValue

```
        boolean selected =   Boolean.parseBoolean(newValue.toString());
```

your going about this in a strange and I guess incorrect way.
If newValue is a Boolean, (check with instanceof) then just cast newValue to be a Boolean.

```
        boolean selected =   (Boolean) newValue;
```

Is that what your trying to achieve?

Comment: @Lidia why don't you post ur solution